# Serialize using class?

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently using `id` values in `div` tags to `serialize`, i.e:

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
    <div id="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_2">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_3">some content here</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(this).sortable('serialize', {key: 'item'})
```

That works fine.

The problem is that I need to allow the user to dynamically choose which porlet s/he wants on screen where they can have the same portlet on the screen many times if they want, i.e:

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
    <div id="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_2">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_2">some content here</div>
    <div id="portlet_3">some content here</div>
</div>
```

This causes a lot of issues because of the identical `id`s.

Now that I have changed the structure to use `class`es instead of `id`s, i.e:

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div class="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div class="portlet_1">some content here</div>
    <div class="portlet_2">some content here</div>
    <div class="portlet_2">some content here</div>
    <div class="portlet_3">some content here</div>
</div>
```

How do I serialize based on the `class` instead of the `id`?

Here is a more complete extract of the code which doesn't working because it serializes based on `id`s:

jQuery:

```
$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var that = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'some web service here',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { strItems:$(that).sortable('serialize', {key: 'item'}) },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                //some error message here
            },
            success: function() {
                //do something on success
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using an old jquery version 1.4.

Comment: How can your first example work fine if you send `item=1&item=2&item=3` to the server? What do you plan to get finally? Something like `item=1&item=1&item=1&item=2&item=2&item=3`?

Comment: When I get `item=1&item=2&item=3`, I split it and use it accordingly at the server level.  Yes, the end example you have shown is exactly what I am after `item=1&item=1&item=1&item=2&item=2&item=3` based on the HTML in the example above.

Comment: Then the easiest will be to update your jQuery and use `attribute` option (as in @JBRTRND answer): http://jsfiddle.net/WTTsB/.

Comment: I'm wondering if I will end up with any issues updating my jQuery version?  Will I run into backwards compatibility issues where code written for 1.4 will not work with the newer versions?

Comment: It should. However, it's worth to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(this).sortable('serialize', {key: 'item', attribute: 'class'});
```

jQuery UI 1.8 [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-serialize) :

> The possible options are: 'key' (replaces part1[] with whatever you want), 'attribute' (test another attribute than 'id') and 'expression' (use your own regexp).

Comment: I've just tried this and I get `item=all` with jQuery 1.4.  I will try updating my jQuery version to 1.8 and am hoping not to run into any backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: @oshirowanen I think it's always better to use the latest version of jQuery rather than do crafts.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by hand:

```
data: function(){
    var mySerial;
    $(this).find('div').each(function(){
        var raw = $(this).attr('class');
        var el = raw.split('_');
        mySerial += el[0]+"[]="+el[1]+"&";
    });
    return mySerial.substr(0,(mySerial.length-1));
}
```

this should return something like this: 
`portlet[]=1&portlet[]=1&portlet[]=2`...

Comment: I will give this a try if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

This this gist.

```
jQuery('.class_input').serializeAnything()
```

https://gist.github.com/4482228

```
(function($) {

$.fn.serializeAnything = function() {

var toReturn = [];

$.each(this, function() {

if (this.name && !this.disabled && (this.checked || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName) || /text|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) {

var val = $(this).val();

toReturn.push( encodeURIComponent(this.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( val ) );

}

});

return toReturn.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");

}


})(jQuery);
```